# Python3 - How to stop ThreadPoolExecutor waiting for threads/futures to finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I have ThreadPoolExecutor running some tasks every 30 seconds.

The download_image task takes 5 seconds to complete.
The backup_project task takes 30 seconds to complete.

The code will only continue when both tasks have completed.

I would like the code to continue right away and reach the `time.sleep(10)`

When the while loop starts again, if backup_project is still running, do nothing.

If backup_project has finished, start/submit a new thread.

I have this code running as a systemd service on CentOS, so it needs to be in a while loop. I want it to check if there are tasks that need doing every 10 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import time

def download_image(message):
    print(f"DOWNLOADING IMAGE...{message}\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"DOWNLOAD FINISHED\n")
    
def backup_project(message):
    print(f"BACKINGUP PROJECT...{message}\n")
    time.sleep(30)
    print(f"BACKUP FINISHED\n")

def main():
    while True:
        print("WHILE LOOP START\n")
        
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            
            future = executor.submit(download_image, ("TEST1"))
            future = executor.submit(backup_project, ("TEST2"))
            
        print("WHILE LOOP FINISH\n")
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach: I use 2 `Event` objects, 1 for each task. That is how I know if both tasks are finished. Code:

```py
import logging
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s: %(threadName)-s: %(message)s"
)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()


def download_image(message, event):
    LOGGER.debug(f"DOWNLOADING IMAGE...{message}")
    time.sleep(5)
    LOGGER.debug(f"DOWNLOAD FINISHED")
    event.set()  # Signal that the task is fininished


def backup_project(message, event):
    LOGGER.debug(f"BACKINGUP PROJECT...{message}")
    time.sleep(30)
    LOGGER.debug(f"BACKUP FINISHED")
    event.set()  # Signal that the task is fininished


def main():
    download_finished = threading.Event()
    backup_finished = threading.Event()
    download_finished.set()
    backup_finished.set()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        LOGGER.debug("WHILE LOOP START")
        while True:
            if download_finished.wait(timeout=1) and backup_finished.wait(timeout=1):
                LOGGER.debug("Start a new batch")
                download_finished.clear()
                backup_finished.clear()
                executor.submit(download_image, "TEST1", download_finished)
                executor.submit(backup_project, "TEST2", backup_finished)
            else:
                LOGGER.debug("Tasks are not finished")

            time.sleep(10)
        LOGGER.debug("WHILE LOOP FINISH")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
DEBUG: MainThread: WHILE LOOP START
DEBUG: MainThread: Start a new batch
DEBUG: ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0: DOWNLOADING IMAGE...TEST1
DEBUG: ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1: BACKINGUP PROJECT...TEST2
DEBUG: ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0: DOWNLOAD FINISHED
DEBUG: MainThread: Tasks are not finished
DEBUG: MainThread: Tasks are not finished
DEBUG: ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1: BACKUP FINISHED
DEBUG: MainThread: Start a new batch
...
```

#### Notes

- I put the while loop inside the `ThreadPoolExecutor` context
- For each task, I pass in an event object, which the task will set upon finishing
- When dealing with multi-threading, it is a good idea to use the `logging` library rather than using `print`